# Cannot connect to domain

Tags: authentication, networking, kerberos, samba, radius

I'm having a problem to connect to my domain. I want to connect RADIUS Centos (Linux) with my AD (Windows server 2019).
Here is the problem:[error][6]

```
As you can see kerberos finds user and passes true. But when I try to join domain, it show's an error.

Here is my config's of samba and kerberos. 

[kerberos][1]
[resolv][2]
[samba.cnf][3]
[ip][4]
[windows dns server][5]




  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2MCi.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zO7mu.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OP6uc.png
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6aX1.png
  [5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrfTZ.png
  [6]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlDp3.png
```

Problem was solved with pfsense enabling dns resolve.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be running a kdc on your Unix domain member, your krb5.conf is incorrect, finally, your smb.conf is incorrect, it doesn't have any 'idmap config' lines.
Can I suggest you read this:
https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Setting_up_Samba_as_a_Domain_Member

Also if sssd is running, stop it and remove it, you can no longer use Samba with sssd, you must install and use winbind.

Comment: I fixed alot, but the main problem was with pfsense. Okay but now I have a problem with DNS update fail.. Any help ?